# What is the difference between fold expressions ####, # ----, and # ==== in RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

I have been using `# ----` to compartmentalize code in sections. Today, I discovered `# ====` by accident and noticed that both RStudio fold expressions serve the same purpose. I looked into the documentation and noticed that `####` works the same way as well.

Are there nuanced ways to use fold expressions in RStudio?

Comment: Official documentation - https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200484568-Code-Folding-and-Sections